# Order by most relations in Spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to develop a social network in Angular and Spring.

I have users and they can follow eachother.
My User class looks something like this.

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "following")
    private List<Follow> followers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "follower")
    private List<Follow> following;

}
```

Is there anyway I can get all the users ordered by the number of followers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your UserRepository you could try the following...

```
@Query("select u from User u order by u.followers.size")
User findAllOrderedByFollowing();
```

Taking full advantage of JPA. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have definitely done this in MySQL; I don't have the query where I did this right on hand though.

I think it is something like

```
select id, count(followers) as indx from ..., collate by id, order by indx
```